# Is my thinking of half wave voltage Tripler Circuit right?

Tags: voltage, diodes, voltage-doubler

Is my thinking of half wave voltage Tripler Circuit right?because my thinking  is a little bit different from the book's

**Book**
Let the input is a sine wave with amplitude \$=V_m\$
[image]

1.When input is the first positive half wave,\$D_1\$ on,and \$C_1\$ will be charge to \$V_m\$

2.When input is the first negative half wave,\$D_1\$ off,and \$D_2\$ on ,and \$C_2\$ will be charge to \$2V_m\$

3.When input is the second positive half wave,\$D_1\$ on, \$D_2\$ off,and \$D_3\$ on ,and \$C_3\$ will be charge to \$2V_m\$

now the \$V_O=V_{C1}+V_{C3}=3V_m\$

**My opinion**
[image]

1.When input is the first positive half wave,\$D_1\$ and \$D_3\$ on,and \$C_1\$ and \$C_3\$ will be charge to \$V_m\$

[image]
2.When input is the first negative half wave,and we add the sine input with the voltage of \$C_1\$,the amplitude of input will become \$2V_m\$,now  \$D_1\$ and \$D_3\$ off,\$D_2\$ on ,and \$C_2\$  will be charge to \$2V_m\$

[image]

3.When input is the second "positive" half wave,and we add the sine input with the voltage of \$C_2\$,the amplitude of input will become \$3V_m\$, and \$D_1\$ and \$D_3\$ on,and \$C_3\$will be charge to \$3V_m\$.and the voltage of \$C_3\$ is the \$V_o\$

I want to ask is my thinking about the half wave voltage Tripler Circuit right?if wrong,which part of my thinking is wrong,can anyone tell me?thx a lot!

Comment: that works with negative 3x pk  relative to the top line AC if you define that as 0Vdc. (or neutral).  Same but inverted to convention.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 So you think my thinking is right?

Comment: You are correct for 101 theory. For 201 add a ground symbol and maybe for 301 theory, try estimating the current spike if you had a switch close at worse case sin (90 deg) using 1 Amp rated 1N400x diodes.  What is your skill level? Could you draw the supply current waveforms during startup?  Are you the same person @XM551 or twice as smart.

Comment: Do you understand the limitations of your assumptions? and how to ask a better question?

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 NO,what is the 101 theory you mention?

Comment: 101 is 1st year education in a course

Comment: sorry i don't understand what you really want to say

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75  what?

Comment: I am suggesting like each year in University course numbering system, there is a more detailed and realistic model of diodes as current rectifiers. (CR)

Comment: for the advanced reader try this simulation and location 0V at source, move it below, reverse all diodes and , RESET to examine startup current  http://tinyurl.com/y7ejs8um

Comment: http://tinyurl.com/yakkldln same thing but shifted 90deg so RESET shows massive surge current  on 10Vp sine